# How to stop backup and sync syncing folder in My Drive

Tags: google-chrome, sync

I have 1 computer connected to Backup & Sync with 3 folders selected - Desktop, Documents, Pictures.

In the Google Drive settings I'm using the option Only Select These Folders and I have a few folders selected.

I want to store an additional folder from an external hard drive in my google drive and not have it synced my local Google Drive folder. I thought my settings would handle that but it's not working. The new folder is being synced and I don't know why.

How do I put files in my Google Drive in the cloud and not have it copied down to my local machine??

Thanks.

Comment: Your settings, if they're as described, should be working. If not then consider removing Google Backup & Sync and reinstalling. It could simply be a configuration error due to upgrading from Google Drive.

Comment: Thanks. An uninstall & reinstall seemed to do the trick. Uninstalled everything including Library>Application Support>Google>Drive

Answer (score 1):

An uninstall & reinstall seemed to do the trick. Uninstalled everything including Library>Application Support>Google>Drive